# How can I maintain the status message after `zz` command?

Tags: search, highlight, message

I like to see the number of matches in a search on the bottom right

```
set shortmess-=S
```

But I also like to center the screen after I search

```
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
nnoremap * *zz
nnoremap # #zz
```

The problem is that after the `zz` command, the number of matches message disappears.

I used to solve this by adding `lN` to the end of those aliases (i.e. `nnoremap n nzzlN`), but that's pretty hacky and also messes up [vim cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool).

Any ideas on how to combine all these ideas properly?

- searches always center the screen
- number of matches is always shown after searching
- vim-cool still works and highlighting disappears after a non-search command

Comment: The core issue is that `zz`, like any attempt to scroll the window, causes a redraw and there is no way to prevent it from happening. It is that redraw that makes the message about matches disappear so you can't really have both. That said, vim-cool can output the number of matches so maybe you could open an issue so that we can work out together a way to integrate `zz`?

Comment: Any idea what the area that displays the match count is called? The line below the statusline is... the "message line?" But the thing is, those search index counts don't show up in `:messages` output. One thought I had was to write a function that gets the most recent message and prints it back out to the message line. But that won't work if the index count is not a "message." If it's not a message, then what is it? What's the stuff in the very bottom right of vim called?

Comment: The line is called "command line".

Comment: Ah, thanks. Unfortunately I think my best immediate solution right now involves not using vim-cool (sad, I know seeing as it is pretty cool) and leaving in the mapping as `nzzlN` to show the match count. Maybe in the future vanilla vim will implement some more controls for the bottom-right stuff (right-justified part of the command line).